# JMeter - Summary Report not displaying correctly

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, summary

I am new to JMeter so bear with me...

I have a `setUp Thread Group` where I am grabbing a token and then re-using that in the `HTTP Header Manager` within the main `Thread Group`.  Within that `Thread Group` I have the following parameters set...

[image]

I run this command to execute the tests:

```
jmeter -n -t PSC_Token.jmx -l testPsc.jtl -f
```

When I open the testPsc.jtl file though in Summary Report, I would expect that each request would show 600 for # Samples (200 threads * 3 loop count) but it is showing 1200 for each.

[image]

I tried deleting the file entirely and re-running it, just in case it was appending or something strange.  That doesn't resolve the issue though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing the same data into the same file 2 times, the options are in:

1. Disable (or better delete) the [Summary Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) listener, in general Listeners don't add any value, they only consume resources
2. Or remove [`-l` command line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) and run your test just like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t PSC_Token.jmx
   ```

Also be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)

Comment: thanks.  That fixed it.  Thanks for the reminder on the upgrade as well, I will do that